# Addition operator inside a while loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, addition

I just started learning Java and I have the following problem.

I need help with this for loop that I have inside a while loop.

```
while (difference > epsilon) {
    for (int u = 0; u <= N, u++) {
        for (int d = 0; d <= N, d++) {
            formulaLong += Math.pow(E, -rT) * Math.pow(0.5, N) * productofVC[u][d];
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the while loop runs, the variable `formulaLong` is added to the previous formulaLong from the previous while loop. How do I code this so that `formulaLong` gives me the formula for the current while loop only?

Comment: Just reset `formulaLong` to zero at the beginning or end of the loop.

Comment: how do I do that? sorry I just started learning java

Comment: Instead of resetting the same variable, simply declare the variable *inside* the while-loop, as in `while ( .. ) { double formulaLong = 0; .. }`. This new variable (which has been assigned a nice default value), is distinct each loop and aides (or so I find) code readability by limiting the variable scope.

Comment: You probably want to include that _does_ something with the value of `formulaLong` before resetting it to zero though.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line .. as i understand from your question !!

```
while(difference > epsilon){
 for (int u = 0; u <= N, u++){
  for (int d = 0; d <= N, d++){
   formulaLong += Math.pow(E, -rT)*Math.pow(0.5, N)*productofVC[u][d];
  }
 }
 formulaLong = 0; // so you reset the value after the for loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could just re-init above your top for loop like this:

```
while(difference > epsilon){
  formulaLong = 0;//reset
  for (int u = 0; u <= N, u++){
     for (int d = 0; d <= N, d++){
         formulaLong += Math.pow(E, -rT)*Math.pow(0.5, N)*productofVC[u][d];
     }
  }
}
```

Not real sure how your while loop will ever stop though.